# Как получить программно descriptor-ы таблиц?

Tags: delphi

Помогите получить програмно descriptor-ы таблиц, не полей. Попробовал через FIB-ы (FIB_Table.Description) - возвращается пустое значение, хотя я его заводила и
могу просматривать IBExpert-ом.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить ваши descriptor'ы, смотрите RDB$DESCRIPTION в RDB$RELATIONS.